# Xamarin Pass Parent BindingContext Value to Converter

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a master list of selectable cars, and a second list containing the IDs of the selected cars.

```
public class SelectCarsViewModel : BindableBase 
{
    public IList<Car> Cars = new List<Car>();
    public IList<string> SelectedCars = new List<string>();
}

public class Car
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

I need to display a check mark next to every selected car.  I'm trying to accomplish this by developing a converter which takes the ID of the current car, and the `SelectedCars` list.  I'm having difficulty passing the `SelectedCars` list from XAML.  I'm able to pass SelectCarsPage, but not its BindingContext nor its SelectedCars property.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="SelectCarsPage">
    <ListView ItemsSource=Cars>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource IsCarSelected}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={x:Reference Name=SelectCarsPage}, Path=SelectedCars}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>

public class IsCarSelected : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //parameter is SelectCarsPage and not the SelectedCars list.

        //I'd eventually like to get the following to work
        var selectedCars = (List<string>)parameter;
        return selectedCars.Contains(value.ToString()) ? "√" : "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Label Text="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource IsCarSelected}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={x:Reference Name=SelectCarsPage}, Path=BindingContext.SelectedCars}}"/>
```

When you perform a binding reference/source, you don't bind to the BindingContext but to the control itself. If you want to access to a property from its BindingContext (the view model), you have to set the path like this :

```
Path=BindingContext.SelectedCars
```

This kind of binding hits the control itself because it allows to get the value of properties such as the height, width, visibility and so on. If you need a property from its BindingContext, use the BindingContext object and then, target the property you need.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about to create a new class that inherit from Car class like this one

```
public class CarWithSelectionInfo : Car
    public bool Selected {get; set;}
end class
```

and manage it in your view model instead create 2 different lists?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply add a "IsSelected" boolean property to your "Cars" model. Set to "true" or "false" the property...

Then your ValueConverter should be something like

```
if(value != null && value is bool){

    if(((bool)value) == true)
        return "√";
    else
        return "";
}
else
    return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

var source = (parameter as Binding).Source as ListView;
if (source == null) return result;

var itemSource = source.ItemsSource as IList;